# Javascript code to find prime numbers doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I run this function, which i triggered with a button, and it should be printing the prime numbers. Instead, it printed all the numbers that it checked. The user is supposed to enter a number(for example 100) and all the numbers lower than it will be checked if they are prime, and if they are, they will be printed.(i is the number that is being checked)

```
function findeprime(num) {
    for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        for (coun = 2; coun < i; coun++) {
            if (i % coun == 0) continue;
        }
        document.write(i + " is prime <br/>");
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `continue` is only breaking out of the inner loop. I'd recommend something like this

```
function findeprime(num) {
    var isPrime;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        isPrime = true;
        for (coun = 2; coun < i; coun++) {
            if (i % coun == 0) isPrime = false;
        }
        if (isPrime) document.write(i + " is prime <br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: To be a bit more efficient, you can simply check up to the square root of the input number ;)

Comment: Oh absolutely. I mean, even the ultra-naive approach of checking up to `i/2` would offer significant gains here.

Comment: As you said my continue is breaking out of the inner loop. But since the number that is being checked isn't prime, we want to continue, and start checking the next number. Sorry for these questions, I'm new to javascript.

Comment: Sorry I should rephrase. It wasn't breaking out of the inner loop, it was simply making it go on to the next value of `coun`. So no matter what it would still check every value in `2 . . . i`, and then at that point it would say `i is prime`, even though it had continued potentially multiple times. By adding a flag, we only reach that print statement if we never found a value of `coun` such that `i % coun == 0`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your continue statement is misplaced. It is affecting the inner loop while your code will work properly only if it affected the outer loop.

Since you can't have a continue statement affect an outer loop/block, try the following:

```js
function findeprime(num) {
    for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        var prime = true;
        for (coun = 2; coun < i; coun++) {
            if (i % coun == 0) {
              prime = false;
              break;
            }
        }
        if(prime) alert(i + " is prime");
    }
}

findeprime(14);
```

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, your `continue` is breaking the script out of the wrong loop.  You can alternatively [label the loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue#Using_continue_with_a_label) you want to break out of:

```js
function findeprime(num) {
    checknum: for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        for (coun = 2; coun < i; coun++) {
            if(i % coun == 0) continue checknum;
        }
        document.write(i + " is prime <br/>");
    }
}
findeprime(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently everyone already gave you the answer, however i´m gonna post an additional example, for knowledge purposes.

```js
Number.prototype.isPrime = function() {

  for (var i = 2; i < this; i++) {
    if (this % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;

};

function findPrimes(num) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    if (i.isPrime()) results.push(i);
  }
  return results;
}

var primes = findPrimes(1000);

document.write(primes.join(', '));
```